# how to use complex object to insert data in more than one table related "Entity Framework 4.1"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, entity-framework-4.1

I would like to know is there any way to use complex type to insert data in more than one table
if I have a parent object has a collection of child object and I need to insert data in the parent and its child too
Example: This is the parent object "Video" and its Child VideoData Diagram
[image]

Please advice

Comment: What do you mean by "use complex type"?  Do you mean your source data comes from a complex object?  Or are you referring to your entities as the complex object?

Answer (score 1):

EF will update all modified entities/properties automatically. So if you create a new VideoData, set it's language, and append it to the VideoDatas collection of a Video instance, then call

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

EF will add the VideoData to the db, setting the Language, then update the Video record. It walks up and down the graph saving any changes. You just need to make sure you are using `context` to get the entities in the first place so EF can track it.